# Dynamic array reallocation

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to create a dynamic list but for some reason the list does not grow more than 2 elements

```
    typedef struct{
    char* name;
    int age;
} student;

int Insert(void){
    int const MAX = 1000;
    int age;
    char name[MAX];
    int i=1;
    int const ENOGH = 2;
    int const AGE_ERR = 1;
    int flag=0;

    student** array = NULL;
    do{
        printf("insert student name\n");
        printf("user: ");
        scanf("%s",name);
        if( strcmp(name,"enough") != 0){
            printf("insert age\n");
            printf("user: ");
            scanf("%d",&age);
        }else{
            return ENOGH;
        }
        if ( age == -1){
            flag = AGE_ERR;
        }
        if (age != AGE_ERR){
            array = realloc(array, sizeof(student*)*(i+1));
            array[i] = malloc(sizeof(student));
            if (array[i] == NULL){
                printf("Erorr\n");
            }
            array[i]->name =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(name)+1));
            strcpy(array[i]->name ,name);
            array[i]->age = age;
            i++;
        }
    }while (flag != AGE_ERR);

    return AGE_ERR;
}
```

I am sure it has something to do with the reallocation of the pointer to the list and the list elements allocations, but I can not find what

(while loop never end to save some code)

Comment: *list does not grow more than 2 elements* - how do you know?

Comment: @EugeneSh. debugging

Comment: @gbox That's a very bad answer to a good question - so again: How do you know it does not grow?

Comment: @gbox See here https://ideone.com/asxKgv This shows 4 elements. So that works fine. However, I don't understand why you start from `int i=1;` ? Why not `int i=0;`

Comment: @4386427 I watch the array grow on the debugger, I understand that I must print rather then look at the debugger, sorry, I am not a good programmer

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
 array[i]->name =(char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(name)));
```

The `strlen` function returns an `int`, so `sizeof(strlen(name))` evaluates to the size of an `int`.  That is most likely not long enough for whatever string you are storing.

You instead want:

```
 array[i]->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1));
```

This allocates space for the string *plus* the terminating null byte.  You could actually replace both this line and the `strcpy` that follows it with a call to `strdup`:

```
 array[i]->name = strdup(name);
```

Comment: Correct, I fixed it, but still the array does not grow, posted the full code

Comment: @gbox It seems to work fine for me. How do you know it's not growing?  Be **specific**.

Comment: When entering the third student the list does not save him

Comment: @gbox Again, *how do you know that?*